# Not getting expected results in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, peoplesoft

I have a query with 5 prompts

```
:1 - EMPLID
:2 - APPL_NBR
:3 - CHECKLIST_CD
:4 - CHECKLIST STATUS
:5 - ADMIT_TERM
```

The problem with my query is that it does not follow the results of the criteria given below:

1. There are no mandatory prompts, so if the report is run where all the criteria are blank, then the following will happen:

   - All students with incomplete / in progress checklists will be shown regardless of when they were created.
   - All students whose checklists were completed within the current Term will be shown.
2. If the (past) Admit term is specified, cases from e-i will show the completed checklists of the specified term.
3. If the (past) Admit term is specified, only checklists that have been created during that term who are still incomplete / in progress checklists will be shown.
4. If a future Admit term is specified, then only the current incomplete / in progress checklists will be show.

Here is the sql:

```
SELECT A.EMPLID, A.NAME, A.ADM_APPL_NBR, A.ADMIN_FUNCTION, A.STDNT_CAR_NBR, 
A.ACAD_CAREER, A.APPL_PROG_NBR, A.ADMIT_TERM, A.CHECKLIST_CD, A.DESCRSHORT, 
A.CHECKLIST_STATUS, TO_CHAR(A.STATUS_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD'), 
TO_CHAR(A.DUE_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD'), A.COMM_COMMENTS, A.SEQ_3C, A.CHKLST_ITEM_CD, 
A.DESCR, A.ITEM_STATUS, TO_CHAR(A.UM_STATUS_DT_CL,'YYYY-MM-DD'), 
TO_CHAR(A.UM_DUE_DT_CL,'YYYY-MM-DD'), A.RESPONSIBLE_ID 
FROM PS_UM_7902_VW2 A 

--for Condition 1, for prompts with no values provided
WHERE ( 1 = 1 AND EMPLID LIKE DECODE (:1, '', '%', :1) 
 AND ADM_APPL_NBR LIKE DECODE(:2, '', '%', :2) 
 AND CHECKLIST_CD LIKE DECODE(:3, '', '%', :3) 
 AND A.CHECKLIST_STATUS = :4 
 OR '' = :4 
 AND A.CHECKLIST_STATUS = 'I' 
 OR ( A.CHECKLIST_STATUS = 'C' 
 AND SYSDATE BETWEEN A.TERM_BEGIN_DT AND A.TERM_END_DT) 
 AND ( A.ADMIT_TERM = A.STRM 
 AND SYSDATE BETWEEN A.TERM_BEGIN_DT AND A.TERM_END_DT) 
 -- end for Condition 1

 OR A.EMPLID = :1 
 AND ( 1 = 1 AND ADM_APPL_NBR LIKE DECODE(:2, '', '%', :2) 
 AND CHECKLIST_CD LIKE DECODE(:3, '', '%', :3) 
 AND A.CHECKLIST_STATUS = 'I' 
 OR ( A.CHECKLIST_STATUS = 'C' 
 AND SYSDATE BETWEEN A.TERM_BEGIN_DT AND A.TERM_END_DT) 
 AND ( A.ADMIT_TERM = A.STRM 
 AND SYSDATE BETWEEN A.TERM_BEGIN_DT AND A.TERM_END_DT)) 
 OR A.ADM_APPL_NBR = :2 
 AND ( 1 = 1 AND EMPLID LIKE DECODE (:1, '', '%', :1) 
 AND CHECKLIST_CD LIKE DECODE(:3, '', '%', :3) 
 AND A.CHECKLIST_STATUS = 'I' 
 OR ( A.CHECKLIST_STATUS = 'C' 
 AND SYSDATE BETWEEN A.TERM_BEGIN_DT AND A.TERM_END_DT) 
 AND ( A.ADMIT_TERM = A.STRM 
 AND SYSDATE BETWEEN A.TERM_BEGIN_DT AND A.TERM_END_DT)) 
 OR A.CHECKLIST_CD = :3 
 AND ( 1 = 1 AND EMPLID LIKE DECODE (:1, '', '%', :1) 
 AND ADM_APPL_NBR LIKE DECODE(:2, '', '%', :2) 
 AND A.CHECKLIST_STATUS = 'I' 
 OR ( A.CHECKLIST_STATUS = 'C' 
 AND SYSDATE BETWEEN A.TERM_BEGIN_DT AND A.TERM_END_DT) 
 AND ( A.ADMIT_TERM = A.STRM 
 AND SYSDATE BETWEEN A.TERM_BEGIN_DT AND A.TERM_END_DT)) 
 OR A.CHECKLIST_STATUS = :4 
 AND ( 1 = 1 AND EMPLID LIKE DECODE (:1, '', '%', :1) 
 AND ADM_APPL_NBR LIKE DECODE(:2, '', '%', :2) 
 AND CHECKLIST_CD LIKE DECODE(:3, '', '%', :3)) 
 OR ( A.CHECKLIST_STATUS = 'C' 
 AND SYSDATE BETWEEN A.TERM_BEGIN_DT AND A.TERM_END_DT) 
 AND ( A.ADMIT_TERM = A.STRM 
 AND SYSDATE BETWEEN A.TERM_BEGIN_DT AND A.TERM_END_DT) 

 --for Conditions 2, 3 and 4 for ADMIT_TERM
 OR A.ADMIT_TERM = :5 
 AND 1 = 1 AND EMPLID LIKE DECODE (:1, '', '%', :1) 
 AND ADM_APPL_NBR LIKE DECODE(:2, '', '%', :2) 
 AND CHECKLIST_CD LIKE DECODE(:3, '', '%', :3) 
 AND (( SYSDATE > A.TERM_END_DT 
 AND A.CHECKLIST_STATUS = 'C') 
 OR SYSDATE BETWEEN A.TERM_BEGIN_DT AND A.TERM_END_DT) 
 AND ( A.CHECKLIST_STATUS = 'I' 
 OR ( SYSDATE < A.TERM_BEGIN_DT 
 AND A.CHECKLIST_STATUS = 'I')));
 -- end for Conditions 2, 3 and 4
```

I have isolated the part where I did conditions 1, 2, 3 and 4. Most of the parts in the middle are working fine with their given conditions. Have I done anything wrong? Especially in the first part where I think it should be easy to pull all values for that prompt as default.

Appreciate all the help I can get.

Thanks!

Comment: That's a big hunk of SQL to ask someone to figure out.  Please post a [mcve]

Comment: You isolated scenarios and stuff but... without sample input and expected output it's hard to know what is your problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your main issue is in using `''` to represent `null`. I would recommend not doing that, since other languages treat empty strings very differently than SQL does.

So first, `decode` is frowned upon these days, for several reasons. Instead of e.g.

```
EMPLID LIKE DECODE (:1, '', '%', :1)
```

I'd just do

```
EMPLID LIKE NVL(:1, '%')
```

Second, and this is probably the part giving you trouble, these lines aren't doing what you want:

```
AND A.CHECKLIST_STATUS = :4 
OR '' = :4
```

The second line will never be true. Any comparison against a null will be null, not true. So `'' = ''` will return null, not true. And it's generally considered good practice to use parentheses with mixed AND/OR, for clarity. So instead, I would do something like this:

```
AND (A.CHECKLIST_STATUS = :4 OR :4 is null)
```

Comment: PeopleSoft on Oracle disallows NULL for every data type except Date/DateTime/Time fields and long text fields (e.g. DESCRLONG field)

Comment: @qyb2zm302:  Oracle treats an empty string as null, and any comparison with a null value must use `is null`, or will be false.  ...so kfinity has this part right.